SQLServer TDS + Arith Abort DSN Format
I'm quite new to this, but how can the TDS Version and Enable Arith Abort options be added to the DSN?
dsn := "sqlserver://username:password@hostname:port?database=database_name&encrypt=false"

db, err := sql.Open("mssql", dsn)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

I'm currently using the https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb.

Why would you do that? airthabort you can set by executing the option SET. For TDS-version, it's usually up to the driver + server to decide

The TDS version doesn't matter and settings aren't set on the connection string. The driver may have already set ANSI_DEFAULTS to ON already.  What's the real problem? Why do you care about these?


Searching in the go-mssqldb repo for various settings like eg ANSI_NULLS I found : How to use the Connector object. You can set options through connector.SessionInitSQL, eg connector.SessionInitSQL = "SET ANSI_NULLS   ON".


I'm trying to figure out how to add/convert the options from node-mssql (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) to Go. The database connection is based on different TDS versions and should have disabled the Arith Abort. @panagiotis-kanavos

Honestly, disabling ARITHABORT sounds like a bit of an XY Problem

Arithabort off is a really bad idea. The database connection is based on different TDS version you mean you have a need to connect to both sql server 2000 and 2022? Are you reimplementing JTDS by chance?

No it's not based on different TDS versions. TDS is the communication protocol, something handled by the driver (JDBC, ODBC, OLEDB). Unfortunately some languages use the rather quirky FreeTDS library instead of the actual drivers. The quirks can be elephant-sized. In the past FreeTDS didn't even support query parameters because the maintainers thought they were rarely used. Currently, it can't handle Unicode in bulk copy operations. Both are rather amusing assumptions to the hundreds of thousands (if not millions) of developers using nvarchar parameters for the past 25+ years.

&encrypt=false why? If you run into certificate issues, either find and use a valid certificate or use Trust Server Certificate=yes.

The reason why the Arith Abort needs to be disabled is it messes up with the old versions of the database.

Same reason with Arith Abort, it messes up with old versions of the database @panagiotis-kanavos

No it doesn't. Unless you mean some SQL Server 7 database from the 1990s. You really need to explain what's going on because it seems there are critical problems. Changing the switch may cover up the problem only to result in incorrect results or slow queries.

Same reason with Arith Abort what does that mean? No driver needs to specify the TDS protocol version. Either they support the server or not. NodeJS packages are no kind of reference - Node didn't even exist when SQL Server 2008, the most common unsupported version was released. I can understand a FreeTDS wrapper package requiring a specific FreeTDS version number, due to that library's quirks

Did a Node application write to the database with ARITH_ABORT OFF, ignoring math errors in queries? Are you trying to migrate to Go now, and find the incorrect queries now throw? Fix the queries or the data instead of trying to maintain the bugs.

I'm trying to migrate an old code into Go and it has an option for the TDS Versions and Arith Abort. The TDS Version must include >=7.1 when connecting to different databases and have the Arith Abort disabled.

You aren't reading the comments. Take it from a SQL Server MVP - that's not how SQL Server works. The behavior of some Node package doesn't reflect the real SQL Server behavior or how other languages work. You didn't even explain what NodeJS driver you used. mssql itself isn't the driver. You used either MSNodeSQLv8 or Tedious. I already showed you how to shoot your foot, ie specify SET ARITHABORT OFF. That's a bug though and must be fixed instead of covered up

Have you tried connecting using connector.SessionInitSQL yet ?

The Arith Abort was directly added to the database config connection. And yes, it is Tedious.
options: {tdsVersion: db_tds_version, enableArithAbort: false}
I was just trying to follow the specifications I've got for now and I can't test the database connection right away as I need vpn related stuff.

What does Tedious have to do with Go???? Those aren't specifications, it's just how a Node library works. Nothing else. Did you actually try using SessionInitSQL? as I need vpn related stuff no you don't, you can run SQL Server on your machine for free. You can install it or run it in a container

Quickstart: Run SQL Server Linux container images with Docker shows how to download and run a SQL Server container. SQL Server Developer edition is free and has the same features as Enterprise - it's just not licensed for production.
